# Is there a way to create a SharePoint Document Library from a List Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, designer-workflow

I have a custom List application and we need to be able to create a document library or document folder  from that app via workflow or javascript.

is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a SharePoint 2013 platform workflow using SharePoint Designer 2013 and use "Call HTTP Web Service" action to do that.

A blog for your reference:
[How To Create A List Using HTTP Web Service In SharePoint Designer 2013 Workflow](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-create-a-list-using-http-web-service-in-sharepoint-designer-2013-workflow/)

Comment: looking for the easiest way to either via javascript or workflow create a document library in an existing site.